# Get Url Alias in Algolia

Tags: path-aliases

I have implemented an Algolia search in my drupal instance and would like to use the node url alias (/some-example-path) rather than node id (/node/{nodeId}). Is there a quick and easy way to do this using the Search API?

Answer (score 1):

For D7: Under the **Configuration -> Search and Metadata -> Search_API** and then go to the **Algolia Index** and **Filters tab** (path will be like: `/admin/config/search/search_api/index/algoliaindex/workflow`, where `algoliaindex` is the machine name of your Algolia index), then under **Data Alterations->Enabled data alterations** check the **URL field** box.   This will add a field to your Algolia index called `search_api_url`.

TIP: If you want to be able to search for text anywhere in the node (not just in indexed fields, you can also check the **Complete entity view** option.  Under  **Processors** for **Complete entity view** use the **HTML filter**.  Under **Processor settings** at the bottom of the page, for **HTML filter->Fields to run on** check **Entity HTML output** and delete all contents from the **Tag boosts** field (otherwise it will index the boosts as well and you'll have to change your displayed search index values on the front-end).  This will then add a plain-text version of the node as a field in your index called `search_api_viewed` that you can display in your search results.

[image: screenshot of Search_API->Filters configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Using Search API in Drupal 8, you could write a custom processor to create dynamic custom fields which will then be indexed by Algolia, Solr or whatever Search API supports.

Documentation: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/search-api/developer-documentation/create-custom-fields-using-a-custom-processor

Answer (score -1):

Use [PathAuto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for
> various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without
> requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you
> to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123.
> The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which
> the administrator can change.

For learn how work with it read [How to Use Pathauto in Drupal 8](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/pathauto/)

Comment: Thank you, I currently have Pathauto setup to allow for these, but the problem I am having is sending the url alias from drupal to algolia for indexing. I do not see an available field for these values to send to algolia. I am using the search api plugin to select the node fields I send.

Comment: @travisbrkr1234 which module you are using to integrate drupal with algolia?

Comment: I am using the Search API module to configure the index (https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) and (https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_algolia) to send the fields to algolia.

Comment: I suppose the better question would be: should I be extending the search api module to allow me to index the url aliases? or is there some way I can configure the content types to include a field that is the alias?

Comment: I ended up writing my own interceptor for the indexing service. I iterate through the associated nodes and pull the title from the node, clean it up and append it to a url string.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote an interceptor for the indexing service. I iterate through the associated nodes and pull the title from the node, clean the title text of any entities/special characters and append it to a "url string".